# somethings wrong with my DW cs 6?

Tags: web, adobe, dreamweaver

while i'm running dreamweaver cs 6, my cpu usage show high percentage in one core and when i opended processes tab, dreamweacer.exe use cpu 25 of my quad core. i'm using windows 7 64 bit and my adobe in 32 bit. whats wrong with mw DW cs 6? what should i do now? thank you all,,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be caused by using the illicit amtlib.dll as most people that use a legitimate copy aren't affected by the issue.

I doubt it's a bug that was put in intentionally to affect pirates, but it doesn't give Adobe a lot of motivation to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is bug, maybe connected with language extension.

But adobe knows about this and is preparing the patch :-)